# SCRIPT ERROR: citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:739: SCRIPT ERROR: @qb-core/server/player.lua:138:

Tags: error-handling, lua, fivem

I've been getting this error and been stuck on a black loading screen after character selection and don't know where the issue is I downloaded ox-lib and since then have had this issue this is the lines of code it is referring to. (First line specifically.)

```
   if PlayerData.job and PlayerData.job.name and not QBCore.Shared.Jobs[PlayerData.job.name] then PlayerData.job = nil end
    PlayerData.job = PlayerData.job or {}
    PlayerData.job.name = PlayerData.job.name or 'unemployed'
    PlayerData.job.label = PlayerData.job.label or 'Civilian'
    PlayerData.job.payment = PlayerData.job.payment or 10
    PlayerData.job.type = PlayerData.job.type or 'none'
    if QBCore.Shared.ForceJobDefaultDutyAtLogin or PlayerData.job.onduty == nil then
        PlayerData.job.onduty = QBCore.Shared.Jobs[PlayerData.job.name].defaultDuty
    end
```

I've tried to reset server and nothing. Tried to see if others had the same issue and couldn't find any videos or anything, was hoping someone had an idea of what this could be.

Comment: Did you crop the error message? Is this the scheduler or the player file?

Answer (score 0):

I would just delete that top line of code mate and have it start with the PlayerData.job= and get rid of that line with the if Playerdata.job

Comment: PlayerData.job = PlayerData.job or {}
    PlayerData.job.name = PlayerData.job.name or 'unemployed'
    PlayerData.job.label = PlayerData.job.label or 'Civilian'
    PlayerData.job.payment = PlayerData.job.payment or 10
    PlayerData.job.type = PlayerData.job.type or 'none'
    if QBCore.Shared.ForceJobDefaultDutyAtLogin or PlayerData.job.onduty == nil then
        PlayerData.job.onduty = QBCore.Shared.Jobs[PlayerData.job.name].defaultDuty
    end